# Revit API - Rename duct systems instances only

Tags: vb.net, revit-api

I'm new to the Revit API and currently struggling with this piece of code.

What I'm trying to do is get all instances of duct systems in the project and rename them (I plan on using a more complex algorithm in the future then simply adding an "x" at the end of the current name...). However, this code not only renames all instances of duct system, it also renames duct system types and I can't figure how to select only instances of duct system.

```
Public Sub RenameSystems()
    Dim MyUIDoc As Autodesk.Revit.ui.uidocument
    Dim MyDoc As Autodesk.Revit.db.document
    Dim CategoryToFilter As Autodesk.Revit.DB.BuiltInCategory
    Dim OtherElementCollector As Autodesk.revit.DB.filteredelementcollector
    Dim FinalSelection As System.collections.generic.icollection(Of Autodesk.Revit.DB.element)
    Dim currentelement As Autodesk.Revit.DB.element
    
    CategoryToFilter = Autodesk.revit.db.builtincategory.OST_DuctSystem
    Dim MyOtherFilter As New Autodesk.Revit.db.ElementCategoryFilter(CategoryToFilter)
    MyUIDoc = Me.ActiveUIDocument
    MyDoc = Me.activeuidocument.document
    OtherElementCollector = New Autodesk.revit.DB.filteredelementcollector(MyDoc)
    FinalSelection = otherelementcollector.wherepasses(MyOtherFilter).ToElements
    
    Using transaction As New Transaction(MyDoc,"Transaction1")
        transaction.start
        For Each currentelement In FinalSelection
            currentelement.Name = currentelement.Name & "x"
        Next
        Transaction.commit
    End using
End Sub
```

See the attached image for the result.

[image: Rename System Issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter out element types from your FilteredElementCollector.
This can be done with the WhereElementIsNotElementType method.

I don't know VB so I'm not entirely sure on the syntax, but my guess is that you should just need to change this line

```
FinalSelection = otherelementcollector.wherepasses(MyOtherFilter).ToElements
```

to

```
FinalSelection = otherelementcollector.wherepasses(MyOtherFilter).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements
```